# Show that $L^{\infty}(\Omega)^* \neq L^1(\Omega)$ for any nonempty open set $\Omega \subset$ $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces

Homework Question: Show that $L^{\infty}(\Omega)^* \neq L^1(\Omega)$ for any nonempty open set $\Omega \subset$ $\mathbb{R}^d$.

My Solution:

To prove that the dual space of $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$, denoted $L^{\infty}(\Omega)^*$, is not equal to $L^1(\Omega)$, we approach this by finding a continuous linear functional on $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ that cannot be represented by an element of $L^1(\Omega)$.

Recall:

- $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ is the space of essentially bounded measurable functions on $\Omega$.
- $L^1(\Omega)$ is the space of integrable functions on $\Omega$.
- $L^{\infty}(\Omega)^*$ consists of all continuous linear functionals on $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$.

Step 1: Duality between $L^1(\Omega)$ and $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$
For functions $f \in L^1(\Omega)$ and $g \in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$, the functional $\Phi_g$ is defined as $\Phi_g(f)=\int_{\Omega} f(x) g(x) d x$.

This represents how $L^1(\Omega)$ naturally induces functionals on $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$.

Step 2: Seeking a Counterexample
By the Hahn-Banach Theorem, $L^{\infty}(\Omega)^*$ contains more than just the functionals induced by $L^1(\Omega)$. We seek a functional in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)^*$ not expressible in the form of $\Phi_g$ for any $g \in L^1(\Omega)$.

Step 3: Constructing a Counterexample
Consider a measure $\mu$ on $\Omega$ that is singular with respect to Lebesgue measure. Define a functional $\Phi$ on $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ by
$$
\Phi(f)=\int_{\Omega} f d \mu \text {. }
$$

This functional is linear and well-defined on $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$, but cannot be represented by any $g \in L^1(\Omega)$, as $\mu$ is singular.

Conclusion
Since we have identified a functional in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)^*$ that cannot be represented by any element in $L^1(\Omega)$, it follows that $L^{\infty}(\Omega)^* \neq L^1(\Omega)$. This result highlights the complexity of dual spaces in functional analysis, demonstrating that $L^{\infty}(\Omega)^*$ is strictly larger than $L^1(\Omega)$.

--
I would love if you can proofread my solution and let me know if I have done everything correctly! :)

Comment: For $\mu $ singular the integral $\int f d\mu$  may be not well defined on $L^\infty.$ For example $\mu=\delta_t$ where $t\in \Omega .$ However $\int f d\mu$ is well defined for continuous and bounded functions $f.$

Comment: Following up on Ryszard’s comment, because $L^\infty$ technically consists on *equivalence classes* of functions, rather than functions themselves, $\int f d\mu$ is not really well-defined when $\mu$ is a singular measure (since $f$ could differ by a Lebesgue null set and as $\mu$ is singular w.r.t. Lebesgue measure, $\int f d\mu$ could be different for different representing functions $f$ of the same element of $L^\infty$).

Comment: However, also as Ryszard suggested, $\int f d\mu$ is well-defined if you restrict to continuous and bounded $f$. This is important because if two continuous functions differ by a Lebesgue null set, then they must be actually equal as the Lebesgue measure of any nonempty open set is strictly positive. This means the space of continuous bounded functions on $\Omega$ is actually a subspace of $L^\infty(\Omega)$ with no need to consider different representatives. In fact, by similar arguments you can show the norms on the spaces even coincide, so $\int f d\mu$ defines…

Comment: … a bounded linear functional on a subspace of $L^\infty(\Omega)$. This is when you can apply Hahn-Banach: this linear functional can then be extended to a bounded linear functional on the entirety of $L^\infty(\Omega)$. Because this functional does not coincide with anything from $L^1$ on even continuous functions, it must be a linear functional not within $L^1$, which proves what you want.

Comment: The usage of Hahn-Banach (or, more fundamentally, some form of Axiom of Choice) is necessary. If I’m remembering correctly, the dual of $L^\infty$ could be $L^1$ in a universe not satisfying Choice.